# Approximate the Score of a 2048 Game

Tags: code-golf

A game of 2048 goes like this:

- Every move you get another piece - either <kbd>2</kbd> 90% of the time, or <kbd>4</kbd> 10% of the time
- for each 2 equal pieces combined you get a piece of the sum of the two and the sum gets added to your score

## Your task

given a board of a 4x4 game, give the average score of what A game like that would result in.

To calculate it, go the other way around of the game. For example, if there's an <kbd>8</kbd> piece, it's made from <kbd>4</kbd>s. The average score of a 4 piece is 4*90% (90% of the time it's made from combining two <kbd>2</kbd> pieces together and it the other 10% a <kbd>4</kbd> isn't made, but ) = 3.6. As to make an <kbd>8</kbd> you need two <kbd>4</kbd>s, and then you need to combine them to an <kbd>8</kbd>, the result is 3.6*2 + 8 = 15.2.

In pseudocode a calculation for one number could be this:

```
function value (x) {
  if (x > 4) return value(x / 2) * 2 + x
  else if (x == 4) return 4*90%
  else return 0
}
```

but you're free to choose any approach as long as it works the same.

### Clarifications

- The input board will always be from a 4x4 board.
- You can take in the board as an array of the 16 values, as 16 different inputs or even a 2D array if that somehow helps you.
- The input numbers will always be zero or 2 to the power of a positive integer.
- You can discard any errors due to floating point operations (but theoretically the program must implement a correct algorithm).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code wins!

### Test-cases

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] -> 0
[2,4,2,4,4,2,4,2,2,4,2,4,4,2,4,2] -> 28.8
[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4] -> 57.6
[0,0,0,4,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,16,2,2,0,2048] -> 20340.4
[2,16,2048,4096,4,32,1024,8192,8,64,512,16384,16,128,256,32768] -> 845465.2
[8,8,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2048,65536] -> 996799.2
```

Comment: @LuisMendo 90% of the time a given `4` gets made from combining two `2` pieces, while 10% of the time they appear as one and give no score

Comment: @LuisMendo A `4` piece isn't always made from combining two `2`'s, as 10% of the time when a piece spawns in after a move, it starts as a `4`

Comment: Out of 9 spawned `2`'s one can only create `4.5 4`'s, not 9. Shouldn't the average score of a 4 piece be `9/11 * 4 = 3.2727...` ?

Comment: @ovs Even if my math is wrong, the challenge will stay this way. Trying to figure what you mean (and now even why I thought my method was correct)

Comment: if 20 new pieces spawn, 2 *4's* and 18 *2's*. We can create additional 9 *4's* by merging the *2's*. We now have 11 *4's* with a total score of `36` and an average score of `36/11 = 3.2727...`

Comment: @ovs ah, I guess you're right :/

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>51</strike> 48 bytes

<sup>-3 bytes thanks to [Mr. Xcoder!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)</sup>

```python
lambda b:sum(n*max(0,len(bin(n))-4.1)for n in b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU5BDoIwELz7ig2n1hTTllILiX4EOUCUSFIKQUz09dgWIXDTZNLMTHd2tnsP99ZEY3W6jLpoymsBZfp4Nsjsm@KFKNE3g8raIINxKA4MV20PBmoDJR4d145nGSXwB3ICGScgCEzvQviKbHyXELP3E1xiaRSrdrXiTM6dVnAq1Pcy71tpkzSRPh85m3LLFEu4XyOtiJkfj5SYUozbDx5LFzhKv0/5YbG9YsFUP5XJOI5knqc76PraDEgTCMJzQKBCGuPxAw)

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##lU5BDoIwELz7ig2n1hTTllILiX4EOUCUSFIKQUz09dgWIXDTZNLMTHd2tnsP99ZEY3W6jLpoymsBZfp4Nsjsm@KFKNE3g8raIINxKA4MV20PBmoDJR4d145nGSXwB3ICGScgCEzvQviKbHyXELP3E1xiaRSrdrXiTM6dVnAq1Pcy71tpkzSRPh85m3LLFEu4XyOtiJkfj5SYUozbDx5LFzhKv0/5YbG9YsFUP5XJOI5knqc76PraDEgTCMJzQKBCGuPxAw). `n.bit_length()` means `len(bin(n))-2`, which we can compress into `len(bin(n))-4.1`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Nice. I was sure there was some easier way to do number of bits but I blanked for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>101</strike> 100 bytes

```cs
n=>{double k=0,l=0;for(int i=0,j;i<n.Length;l+=k,++i)for(j=4;j<=n[i];j*=2)k=j>4?k*2+j:3.6;return l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDBToQwEL3zFT3CUgmUUllL8WDiaT0YDx42e1jZioVaElo0hvDtWCAazZpIMpnMvM68ea@Fviialo@dFqoEDx/a8FfqFPKoNbjvHW2ORhTgrREncHcUyvV657ZTRSaU2R/gqemeJM9LNiqW90sHahZCyUL63LSuHQPC9hUVmQp2XJXmhUqf1dD3hTdNVAzTKmNqLw602jDk1azK8XW9QX51FQeEttx0rQKSDiN1bhqlG8mDx1YYvhOKu6Wr@DuY5fQIAgzBkr8L9KP4hQ@e9x8h/lpZFSsIQwjOI/0LnGIFofUSEWsmxJYFh1syS4knOES2SqMtmi8Q2yTRPB6neNmKkH1ACZkWLkm64lw6cy1@zwUvX71oIUkSk5lxGMZP)

Lambda function. Takes in an array for the board, and returns a double for the score

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 18 bytes

```apl
+/{⍵×0⌈2.1-⍨≢⊤⍵}¨⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97b@2fvWj3q2Hpxs86ukw0jPUfdS74lHnokddS4CitYdWPOqbClL3P40LyPIK9vdTUI820MELY9UB) or [Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97b@2fvWj3q2Hpxs86ukw0jPUfdS74lHnokddS4CitYdWPOqbClL3P40LyPIK9vdTUI820MELY9W5kFUb6ZjogDCENNJB46OpNtHBC9FUQ2w0gdpsAaUNzcDWGOgYGZhYYLgGJAsU1zExsDQDajUGihgYmehYGFoaAU0wM9ExNQQpMrYwASk1NLLQMTI1AyozN0M3ywKo3gRuOwSCLAYbb2ZqamwWqw4A)

Full program submission.

Port of the Python answer.

### Explanation

```apl
+/{⍵×0⌈2.1-⍨≢⊤⍵}¨⎕
                ¨⎕ to each element of the input:
              ⊤⍵   convert to base 2 digits
       2.1-⍨≢      length - 2.1
     0⌈            maximum with 0
   ⍵×              times the element
+/                 sum the resulting array
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (V8), 58 bytes

```js
b=>b.reduce((a,n)=>a+(z=x=>x>4?z(x/2)*2+x:x-4?0:3.6)(n),0)
```